# $L_2$ as a Hilbert space and $\ell_2$

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, topological-vector-spaces

I know that, if measure $\mu$, with which measure space $X$ is endowed, has a [countable base](http://librarum.org/book/10022/196), i.e. if for any measurable $M\subset X$ there exists a measurable set $A_k\in\mathscr{A}$, where $\mathscr{A}$ is a countable family of sets, such that $\mu(M\triangle A_k)<\varepsilon$, then space $L_2(X,\mu)$ of the equivalence classes of Lebesgue square integrable functions is separable. Moreover $L_2(X,\mu)$ is Euclidean and complete and therefore, if it has an infinite dimension, is a separable Hilbert space, isomorphic to the space of square summable sequences, $\ell_2$, either complex or real concondingly with $L_2(X,\mu)$.

I read (p. 386 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) in Kolmogorov-Fomin's that $\ell_2$ *can be considered as $L_2(X,\mu)$ for $X$ countable* [which I think to mean that $\mu$ has a countable base] *and* $\mu$ *defined on all its subsets and taking value $1$ on every point*.

Does anybody know what it means? If I take $X:=\mathbb{R}$ and Lebesgue linear measure as $\mu$, $X$ ha measure $\mu$ with a countable base, $L_2(X,\mu)$ is $\infty$-dimensional, but $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\quad\mu\{t\}=0$, therefore I have misunderstood the meaning of that sentence. I thank you all for any answer!!!

Comment: No, they mean $X$ countable. And the measure is the counting measure on $X$, $\mu(A) = \operatorname{card} A$. So it is, up to different notations, just the good old $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}) = L^2(\mathbb{N},\zeta) \cong L^2(X,\mu)$ (where $\zeta$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Care to make that an answer?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they do mean that $X$ is a countable [countably infinite] set, and the measure is the counting measure on $X$,

$$\mu(A) = \operatorname{card} A$$

for any subset $A\subset X$. In particular, the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-measurable sets is $\mathfrak{P}(X)$, the entire power set of $X$, and the only null set is $\varnothing$.

Thus for $f\colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ and $A\subset X$, we have

$$\int_A f\,d\mu = \sum_{a\in A} f(a)$$

when the sum exists, and up to the identification of a function with its equivalence class modulo "equal almost everywhere", we have

$$L^2(X,\mu) = \left\{ f\colon X \to \mathbb{C} : \int_X \lvert f\rvert^2 < \infty\right\} = \left\{ f\colon X\to\mathbb{C} : \sum_{x\in X} \lvert f(x)\rvert^2 < \infty\right\} = \ell^2(X).$$

Any bijection between two countably infinite sets is measure-preserving for the counting measures on the respective sets, so all these spaces are isomorphic to the classical $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Wow: very interesting and elegant. I was trying to prove a false interpretation. Thanks such that $\mu$(my thanks)$>\aleph_0$